# How to replace inf in a numpy array with zero

Tags: pandas

I am trying to eliminate an inf from a pandas DataFrame, caused by a division by zero. I have tried several techniques using both DataFrame and ndarray structures:

```
df_fund['dly_retn'].replace(np.inf, 0)
na_fund['dly_retn'].replace(np.inf, 0)
na_dly_retn(~isfinite(na_dly_retn))=0
```

Taking the mean in every case results in `"inf"`

I have searched for two days without finding an answer to what should be a trivial problem.

Answer (score 20):

You have to save the operation in your dataframe. One way is to use the parameter `inplace=True`:

```
df_fund['dly_retn'].replace(np.inf, 0, inplace=True)
na_fund['dly_retn'].replace(np.inf, 0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you @Boud. Obvious once you mentioned it.

Answer (score 6):

you can do it for an entire dataframe as follow:

```
new_df.replace(np.inf, 0, inplace=True)
```